# Caml Query to find items with different values in two fields?

Tags: caml-query, taxonomy

In a list, I have two *managed metadata* columns (let's say Tax1 and Tax2).

I'm trying to find all items where values in Tax1 and Tax2 are different.

I'm using this query:

```
  <Where>
    <Neq>
      <FieldRef ID="{4C17C478-4F90-480C-A0F2-0BFAA215807F}"/>
      <FieldRef ID="{05F9E914-EED5-4E19-9561-CE795AD63158}"/>
    </Neq>
  </Where>
  <OrderBy Override="TRUE">
    <FieldRef Name="ID"/>
  </OrderBy>
```

However, I get an error:

```
<nativehr>0x80070057</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>
```

How should I fix my query?

As a side note, my query is fired from a PowerShell script.

Comment: same error with <FieldRef Name='Tax1'/>
        <FieldRef Name='Tax2'/> ?

Comment: @Gyonder: yes. Same error

Answer (score 2):

The query is not properly formatted. You should specify the lookup ID of the term that you want to match. like:

```
<FieldRef LookupId="TRUE" Name="ItemType" />
```

Here is a sample example showing how to work with metadata columns:

```
<Query><Where><In><FieldRef LookupId="TRUE" Name="ItemType" /><Values><Value Type="Integer">14</Value><Value Type="Integer">15</Value></Where></Query>
```

See this for more information: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff625182.aspx

**UPDATE**

I don't think there is any way of detecting when the values of two fields are different. CAML does not support this. You will have to get all data and then do the comparison

Comment: I don't want to match a specific term. I want to find items with two different values in the two fields.

Comment: That is right, the idea here was to inform you that your query format is not correct. You can use whatever operator you need.

Comment: I don't get you. I know my query is incorrect, but you don't tells me how to fix it. I don't understand `whatever operator you need` ... I use `Neq`, isn't it supposed to work?

Comment: @SteveB, see my updated answer.

Comment: I have a very large site collection... this is taking while to compare all items. Anyways thanks for the update

Answer (score 1):

Just found a [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/ab303453-dfd6-46c4-888a-e15d233c8e57/compare-two-fields-in-caml-query) for this.. A possible workaround.

Relevant part:

1. Create calculated column with formula comparing the two fields, final value as boolean
2. Use this column in caml query like any other boolean (yes/no) column

Comment: Taxonomy fields cannot be used in calculated formulas.

Comment: I can only think of performing the comparison is your powershell script then, though I understand that is a less than ideal solution and might not be desirable

Answer (score 0):

I think you should using LINQ.

```
var a= from c in olist.Items.OfType<SPListItem>()
Where convert.ToString("ColumnName1") != convert.ToString("ColumnName2")
select c;
```

[Ref](https://sharesilver.wordpress.com/2011/10/01/comparing-two-fields-of-an-splist-in-sharepoint/)

Comment: Not only, I'm using PowerShell, which exlude Linq usage, but this will still require to process all items in my list.